# How to create multiple variables in a loop and assign values in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have an Excel spreadsheet with several thousand lines of data which is broken up into multiple sections based on the Manager.  I have created coding that hides any lines with a zero value within a range for the individual sections, but they run slow and I'm not sure if there is a faster way to accomplish the same result.  Here is what I have so far:

```
    Option Explicit

    Public shp As Single
    Public r1 As Single
    Public r23 As Single
    Public sFind as String
```

1st part of the coding, which designates the rows to be looped through within the manager group.  I have a button for each Manager and a Sub Button#_Click() to go with each section of data.  Below is an example for Button#1, each look the same other than row numbers being different.

```
    Sub Button1_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    shp = 6
    r1 = 14
    r23 = 36

    Call Button_Macro

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

The above code calls the following code to run:

```
    Sub Button_Macro()

    Dim r as Single
    Dim x as Single
    Dim i as Single
    Dim MyArray as Variant
    Dim ShpName as String

    ShpName = "Rounded Rectangle " & Shp
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(ShpName).Select
    sFind = Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text

    If sFine = "-" Then
         ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(ShpName)).Select
         Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "+"
              Rows(r1 & ":" & r23).Hidden = True
    Else
         ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(ShpName)).Select
         Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "-"

         Rows(r1 & ":" & r23).Hidden = False

         MyArray = Range(Cells(r1,4), Cells(r23,6)).Value

              r = 1
              x = r1
              For i = r1 to r23
                   If MyArray(r,1) + MyArray(r,2) + MyArray(r,3) = 0 Then
                        Rows(x).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                   End If
              x = x + 1
              r = r + 1
              Next i
    End If

    Cells(r1 - 1, 2).Select

    End Sub
```

Next to each section of data there is a button that has a + when all rows in the Manager's section are hidden, then when you click the button it runs the code and changes the button text to - and only shows rows with values greater than zero.  When I click the button, it takes roughly 10 seconds for the code to run.  I know that doesn't sound like much, but people expect that when they click the button the rows with values should appear immediately, not 10 seconds later so I'm trying to find out if there is a faster way of coding this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there are formulas relying on visible cells only then turn `Calculation` to manual in the beginning and back to automatic in the end. Otherwise it will re-calculate on every row hide.

---

Note that instead of using these `Public` variables

```
Public shp As Single
Public r1 As Single
Public r23 As Single
Public sFind as String
```

you should give them as parameters of your procedure. Also row numbers are of type `Long` not `Single` and `sFind` should be a local variable of `Button_Macro` and not `Public`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Button_Macro(ByVal shp As Long, ByVal r1 As Long, ByVal r23 As Long)

    Dim sFind as String

    'your code here …

End Sub
```

And call it like

```
Public Sub Button1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Button_Macro shp:=6, r1:=14, r23:=36

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

---

In this part I would recommend to stop using multiple counters as they all depend on each other the following

```
r = 1
x = r1

For i = r1 to r23
    If MyArray(r,1) + MyArray(r,2) + MyArray(r,3) = 0 Then
        Rows(x).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    x = x + 1
    r = r + 1
Next i
```

can be written as

```
Dim i As Long   'i must be long too
For i = r1 to r23
    If MyArray(i-(r1-1),1) + MyArray(i-(r1-1),2) + MyArray(i-(r1-1),3) = 0 Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  While I agree that your For Loop is more condensed than the one I had, and I used your formatting, it didn't seem to speed up the process much.  What really seemed to help was turning off automatic calculations at the beginning, then turning it back off at the end.  That little piece made all the world of difference!

Comment: @BonnieZ Calculation was what I meant to be the solution. All the other stuff was thought as recommendation to improve the code to make it more solid, this coud not give any further speed of course.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your loop with this one. Yours is convoluted and runs many, many times.

```
For R = R1 To R23
    Myarray = Range(Cells(R, 4), Cells(R, 6)).Value
    If MyArray(1, 1) + MyArray(1, 2) + MyArray(1, 3) = 0 Then
         ActiveSheet.Rows(R).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next R
```

Note that row  and column numbers should be contained in variables of Long data type. That's sufficient because they will never contain fractions which Longs can't handle.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation to change my variables to Long.  I did go ahead and incorporate that piece of your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked out another answer for you which is more comprehensive. It's contained in a single procedure which is called by all the buttons. Depending upon the position of the button it works out which rows to hide, even if you add or delete rows in the future. You can also add or delete buttons.

```
Sub ShowHide_Click()
    ' 020

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Button As Shape
    Dim ButtonName As String, NextName As String
    Dim ButtonID As Integer
    Dim ShowRows As Boolean                     ' True if "+" was clicked
    Dim Rstart As Long, Rend As Long            ' rows to hide
    Dim RowRange As Range
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim R As Long

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet                        ' better name the sheet

    ' get the name of the button that was pressed
    ButtonName = Application.Caller
    Set Button = Ws.Shapes(ButtonName)

    ' read and reset the button
    With Button.TextFrame.Characters
        ShowRows = .Text = "+"
        .Text = IIf(ShowRows, "-", "+")
    End With

    ' assume the first row to hide will be 1 row below the button
    Rstart = Button.TopLeftCell.Row + 1

    ' extract the ID from the name
    Do
        NextName = Right(ButtonName, ButtonID)
        ButtonID = ButtonID + 1
        If ButtonID >= Len(ButtonName) Then Exit Sub
        If Not IsNumeric(Right(ButtonName, ButtonID)) Then Exit Do
    Loop
    ButtonID = Val(NextName)

    ' name the next button in serial sequence
    NextName = Trim(Left(ButtonName, Len(ButtonName) - Len(NextName))) _
                  & Str(ButtonID + 1)
    With Ws
        ' this test will return False if Shape(NextName) doesn't exist
        If .Shapes(NextName).Name = NextName Then
            ' this presumes that the last row to be hidden will be the one
            ' just above the next button's TopLeftCell.
            Rend = .Shapes(NextName).TopLeftCell.Row - 1
        Else
            ' the specified button wasn't found
            ' change column is column B isn't dominant in this regard
            Rend = .Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        End If

        ' set the range attached to the button
        Set RowRange = .Range(.Rows(Rstart), .Rows(Rend))

        ' show or hide rows
        RowRange.Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = Not ShowRows
        If ShowRows Then
            For R = Rstart To Rend
                Arr = Ws.Range(Cells(R, 4), Cells(R, 6)).Value
                Ws.Rows(R).EntireRow.Hidden = (Arr(1, 1) + Arr(1, 2) + Arr(1, 3) = 0)
            Next R

        '    ' consider this alternative (Delete Dim Arr if you choose this)
        '    For R = Rstart To Rend
        '        Ws.Rows(R).EntireRow.Hidden = (Application.Count(Ws.Range(Cells(R, 4), Cells(R, 6))) = 0)
        '    Next R
        End If

        .Cells(Rstart, "B").Select
    End With
End Sub
```

I have added a lot of comments to the code to show how the code works and how to adjust it to work with your worksheet. However, there are a few condition which your worksheet must meet.

1. The buttons must all be of the same type, like "Rounded Rectangle".
2. They must be numbered consecutively. The numbers must not start from 1 (though I can't see why they shouldn't) but they must be numbered consecutively top to bottom. You can't add a button in the middle, like 1, 2, 3, 7, 4, 5, 6. The numbering must be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  While this option is definitely interesting, I can't guarantee that lines won't be added which will require buttons to be added out of sequence.  I am definitely going to hold onto this though for possible future use where I won't have to worry about buttons being added because I really like the idea of having it all in one procedure, rather than having a separate one for each button click.